# How to access X and Y coordinates of the dc.js scatter plot brush?

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, dc.js

Have been trying to access the coordinates of the brush used in scatter plot of dc.js Is there a way just to access the Xaxis and the Yaxis coordinates of edges of the area inside the brush?

Comment: That information should be in `_chart.brush().extent(_);`.  https://github.com/d3/d3-brush#brush_extent

Comment: Or `chart.filter()` should return [dc.filters.RangedTwoDimensionalFilter](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.filters.RangedTwoDimensionalFilter.html) when the brush is active, null otherwise.